# Run code on application crash

Tags: java

I want to run a block of code whenever my server crashes. However, the only way I can think about is to write a client checking if there's open for connections.

Are there any way I can write some code on the actual server, being run just before the server shuts down?

Comment: You could add a Shutdown hook, but when the server crashes, these hooks aren't called. Therefore you must check from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shut down and crash are two very different things. You can have [shutdownHook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) for JVM standard exit, but nothing for the case of crash which means +- nuke to the JVM.

The DOC says:

> In rare circumstances the virtual machine may abort, that is, stop
>   running without shutting down cleanly. This occurs when the virtual
>   machine is terminated externally, for example with the SIGKILL signal
>   on Unix or the TerminateProcess call on Microsoft Windows. The virtual
>   machine may also abort if a native method goes awry by, for example,
>   corrupting internal data structures or attempting to access
>   nonexistent memory. If the virtual machine aborts then no guarantee
>   can be made about whether or not any shutdown hooks will be run.

If shutdown hook is not sufficient you'll need to monitor the app externally.